# Design Pattern - ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

Need to design ASP.net pages which are mostly datadriven pages (read/write to sql tables)
through a interface.

This is mostly for maintence of job queues (to job on hold / delete from queue => which in turn is updating or deleting view.

What would be best Pattern to do with such maintence pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a quick fix, you could try [Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/).

Comment: I agree, Dynamic Data is by far the fastest way to create basic data management pages in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

While I do agree that a good solution for administrivia style sites such a the one you are describing is easily handled by [Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/) as @Robert Harvey has suggested this is not quite a direct answer to your question.

I think you really can't go wrong with using the ASP.NET MVC framework with some DDD concepts tossed in.  This of course may be over architecting a small problem however let me suggest why I like it so much.  With ASP.NET MVC you don't have any heavy obstacles to worry about ...just nice pure HTML.  Form there following a good domain driven design you can quickly get some layers running.  Plug in LINQ to SQL and you are off and running.  With the MVC framework you can also easily make just about everything test driven which will help to keep the site maintainable over time.

I have written a whole series on DotNetSlackers regarding architectural concerns in ASP.NET MVC from a simple app all the way back to a complex distributed SOA style application.  I have one more article (covering the SOA portion) to go to complete the series but there are many other articles in this mini-series that you could get started with.

Take a look at the "[Three Tiers to MVC](http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/StackOverflowInspiredKnowledgeExchange/)" section on this TOC of the bigger series

If this really is an admin site that you are creating though...do take a look at the Dynamic Data option.  Very powerful!

Comment: Yes Andrew its a pure admin site. Will look at Dynamic Data.

Comment: With MVC3/Entity Framework 4.1 and MvcScaffolding from Nuget, you can very quickly and easily build a simple CRUD based website site and still have a nice seperation of concerns via the interface and repositories which the scaffolding can give you.